# Pass stdin into Unix host or dig command

Tags: host, dig

Let's say I have a list of IPs coming into a log that I'm tailing:

```
1.1.1.1
1.1.1.2
1.1.1.3
```

I'd like to easily resolve them to host names. I'd like to be able to

```
tail -f access.log | host -
```

Which fails as host doesn't understand input from stdin in this way. What's the easiest way to do with without having to write a static file or fallback to perl/python/etc.?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use `xargs -l`:

```
tail -f access.log | xargs -l host
```

Comment: This will actually hiccup as host will actually be run with 
    host 1.1.1.1 1.1.1.2

Causing a dns lookup on an invalid DNS server. Setting "-d '\n'" doesn't seem to help it any.

Comment: Use "xargs -l" (or "xargs -L 1") to ensure that the command is run for each line.

Answer (score 6):

You could also use the [read](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_08_02.html#sect_08_02_01) builtin:

```
tail -f access.log | while read line; do host $line; done
```

Answer (score 3):

In the commands below, replace `cat` with `tail -f`, etc. if needed.

**Using `host`:**

```
$ cat my_ips | xargs -i host {}
1.1.1.1.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer myhost1.mydomain.com.
1.1.1.2.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer myhost2.mydomain.com.
```

**Using `dig`:**

```
$ cat my_ips | xargs -i dig -x {} +short
myhost1.mydomain.com.
myhost2.mydomain.com.
```

Note that the `-i` option to `xargs` implies the `-L 1` option.

To first get the IPs of one's host, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27557715/832230).

Answer (score 0):

In bash You can do:

```
stdout | (dig -f <(cat))
```

Example program:

```
(
cat <<EOF
asdf.com
ibm.com
microsoft.com
nonexisting.domain
EOF
) | (dig -f <(cat))
```

This way You only invoke 'dig' once.