# Bash script to get all IP addresses

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to write a `bash` script to get all IP addresses on a server. The script should work on all major distros. Here is what I have:

```
ifconfig | grep 'inet addr:' | awk {'print $2'}
```

Resulting in:

```
addr:10.1.2.3
addr:50.1.2.3
addr:127.0.0.1
```

How can I first remove the `addr:` prefix? Second, how I can exclude `127.0.0.1`?

Comment: not sure if my answer is of help for you, but do you know how to accelerate my little script below ? - it would last at least 5 hours to run through.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no need for `grep`. Here's one way using `awk`:

List only addr:

```
ifconfig | awk -F "[: ]+" '/inet addr:/ { if ($4 != "127.0.0.1") print $4 }'
```

List device and addr:

```
ifconfig | awk -v RS="\n\n" '{ for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i == "inet" && $(i+1) ~ /^addr:/) address = substr($(i+1), 6); if (address != "127.0.0.1") printf "%s\t%s\n", $1, address }'
```

Comment: How hard would it be, to get the `device` eth0, eth1, etc, along with the ip-address?

Comment: I would change the `awk` part like this: `ifconfig | awk -F "[: ]+" '/inet addr:/ && $4 != "127.0.0.1" { print $4 }'` (if is not required) --- You can also use `-F":| +"` as a delimiter.

Answer (score 18):

`ifconfig` was obsoleted by `ip`. It also has the flag `-o` that write outputs easy to parse. Use `ip -4` to show only IPV4 addresses. Note the simpler script, it already exclude the loopback address:

```
ip -o addr | awk '!/^[0-9]*: ?lo|link\/ether/ {print $2" "$4}'
```

Or if you don't want the networks:

```
ip -o addr | awk '!/^[0-9]*: ?lo|link\/ether/ {gsub("/", " "); print $2" "$4}'
```

Comment: Maybe `gsub(/\/.*/,"",$4)`?

Comment: `ip -o addr show scope global | awk '{gsub(/\/.*/, " ",$4); print $4}'`

Comment: ifconfig or ip? Why not just use `hostname -I` ?

Comment: Even better @ScylddeFraud

Answer (score 8):

Simply using [`hostname`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/hostname) you can get a list of all your IP addresses, using the `-I` flag.

i.e.

```
$ hostname --all-ip-addresses || hostname -I
10.10.85.100 10.20.85.100 10.30.85.100
```

whereas

```
$ hostname --ip-address || hostname -i
::1%1 127.0.0.1
```

*Centos7 (k3.10.0)*

Comment: The man page warns `Do not make any assumptions about the order of the output.` That doesn't matter in the scope of the question, but it could matter if you want to use the first IP in the output and assume it is eth0.

Comment: Hmm, doesn't seem very portable. I see this works on Ubuntu because `hostname` is provided by the independent package `hostname`, but on Arch `hostname` is provided by the GNU package `inetutils`, which doesn't have `--all-ip-addresses`.

Answer (score 2):

This is merely a distillation of several prior answers and comments. Sample output is included.

To list IPs:

**Using `ip`:**

(Restricted to IPv4 and global)

```
$ /sbin/ip -4 -o addr show scope global | awk '{gsub(/\/.*/,"",$4); print $4}'
192.168.82.134
138.225.11.92
138.225.11.2
```

**Using `ifconfig`:**

(Excluding 127.0.0.1)

```
$ /sbin/ifconfig | awk -F "[: ]+" '/inet addr:/ { if ($4 != "127.0.0.1") print $4 }'
192.168.82.134
138.225.11.92
138.225.11.2
```

To map IPs to hostnames, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27556861/832230).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a similiar script for what I have tested to get an ip-range of addresses, but
it is slowly - somebody might give a hint, how to accelerate this ? (the ip-range here is an example for to get all lines, who seems to be up - between Vancouver and Korea) :

> #!/bin/bash
>
> for ip in {209..210}.{125..206}.{5..231}.{65..72} 
>   # any ip between 209.126.230.71 and 210.205.6.66
>
> do
>
> printf ' === %s ===\n' "$ip"
>
> whois "$ip" >> /home/$user/test001.txt
>
> done

If this is too trivial or some mistake in it here, simply answer or comment.

This script would last until finish about 5 to 8 hours.

Answer (score 0):

I would to introduce you to a command-line tool called [OSQuery](https://github.com/facebook/osquery/) by Facebook which helps you get system info by making SQL-like queries. For your case for instance, you would have enter;

```
osquery> select * from interface_addresses;
```

Which would output something like;

```
interface = wlan0
       address = 192.168.0.101
          mask = 255.255.255.0
     broadcast = 192.168.0.255
point_to_point =
```

Which I find a lot more neat and convenient.

Answer (score -1):

Use grep -v to ignore 127.0.0.1

```
ifconfig | grep 'inet addr:' | awk {'print $2'} | grep -v '127.0.0.1'
```

Use sed to edit out the 'addr:'

```
ifconfig | grep 'inet addr:' | awk {'print $2'}  | grep -v '127.0.0.1' | sed -e 's/addr://'
```

Comment: You can use `awk` to filter out the loopback address.

Answer (score -1):

`ifconfig | grep 'inet addr:' | awk {'print $2'} | awk 'BEGIN{FS=":"}{print $2}' | grep -v '127.0.0.1'`

Answer (score -1):

if it is only the "addr:" word that you'd like to remove I would use `sed` instead of `awk` like

```
ifconfig | grep 'inet addr:' | awk {'print $2'}| grep -v 127.0.0.1 | sed -e 's/addr://'
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm always surprised to see people using sed and awk instead of perl.

But first, using both grep and awk with an extra option, feel free to just:

```
ifconfig | grep 'inet addr:' | awk {'print $2'} | awk -F: {'print $2'} | grep -v '127.0.0.1'
```

replacing the awks with perl:

```
ifconfig | grep 'inet addr:' | perl -F\\s\|: -ane 'print "$F[2]\n"' | grep -v '127.0.0.1'
```

replacing the greps within the same perl script:

```
ifconfig | perl -F\\s\|: -ane 'next if !/^inet addr:/ or /127\.0\.0\.1/; print "$F[2]\n"'
```

and lastly just using the power of perl's regex:

```
ifconfig | perl -ne 'next if !/inet addr:(?<ip>[0-9.]+)/ or $+{ip} == "127.0.0.1"; print "$+{ip}\n"'
```

Comment: Man - someone hating on the perl.  I get it...  sigh.

Answer (score -2):

```
ifconfig | grep 'inet addr:' | awk {'print $2'} | cut -d ":" -f 2
```

Comment: Just posting a line of code isn't helpful. You should explain what your line does and why you think it's the right answer.